# Use English for installation, but user language in installed Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, gui, language-support, translation, localization

We would like to use the English language during the installation process.

*After that*, we want to be able to add another language.

We tried that by selecting English in the installation stage and add the user's language
after the installation completed.

The results were not acceptable: a big mix of English and the user's language within the GUI of Ubuntu itself and its applications.

Basically, what is the best way to use English during the installation process, and another language after the installation completed, regardless of the exact user language?

Comment: Besically, what is the best way to use Englisch gui during installation, and other language after the installation completed, regardless of which the user language is?

Answer (score 2):

If the translation into a language is not complete, especially if it's not complete with respect to the GUIs of the most important applications, selecting that language as the display language will result in a mix of the language in question and English. Translations are mostly done by volunteers, and if you have an interest in improving the situation for your language, please let your [translation team](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Translations/Contact/Teams) know.

The problem you describe has nothing to do with which language you select at installation. The display language can be changed at any time via [Language Support](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/session-language.html).

As regards the translation of the Ubuntu User Guide in 14.04, as you asked specifically about in [another question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/562276/language-of-ubuntu-on-board-guide) (which I consider to be a duplicate of this question), you can see how large percentage of the strings are translated for respective language at [this page](https://translations.launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+source/ubuntu-docs/+pots/ubuntu-help).

Comment: Thanks for information. Regarding the on-board Guilde problem my question is answered. It is not translated into language of my users not in slightest extent. So I will remove it from Ubuntu, if possible at all. English one will more irritate user than help.

Comment: Regarding GUI languages during installation and of complete Ubuntu installation, that's strange. First attempt was namely to use English for installation, then add or switch to user's language after installation completed. Such proceeding did not provide satisfying results - either Gui in English completely or partially. Nor it helped to repeat the installation, and overwritting with the last installation the previous one. Quite similar effects. Only following helped. To repeat the installation with installer in user's lang., but in prior to it remove all data from previous installation.

Comment: @Marki: There must be some misconception involved, but for me to be able to explain better, you'd need to provide a step-by-step description of how that unsatisfying result happened and be ready to answer follow-up questions. Maybe not so interesting, after all, considering that you now seem to have fixed it.